# Doctor giving nurse advice its okay to visit family during COVID19 pandemic - Is this safe?

Tags: covid-19, virus, coronavirus

My sister is a nurse in Labor and Delivery and for the past 3 months we have advised her to stay away from our parents *(60 and 61)* due to the potential risks with COVID-19.

Recently the lead doctor which she works for told her it was okay for her and her kids to visit our parents *(as long as they are not showing symptoms)*

I am a bit confused since this seems to contradict a lot of the advice the government and other medical experts have given.

Are there significant risks involved with allowing her to visit our parents during this time? 
*She has had no direct contact which she is aware of and she does work twice a week so there is a window where she stays home for 2-3 days.*

Our current state has 30,000+ confirmed cases.

Comment: Does the “lead doctor” have any particular expertise in epidemiology, public health, or infectious diseases? If not, it’d be safe enough to ignore advice that they’re giving outside their area of expertise which conflicts with national policy.

Comment: I've closed this because I think it's essentially asking us for personal medical advice. Answers would have to confirm or refute either government recommendations or her lead doctor.

Comment: There are going to be a lot of questions like this where the political masters say one thing, and the medical experts say another.  Hospitals have also been a poor source of advice.

Comment: Unfortunately you can’t get any consistent “advice” or “guidance” from anyone. At this point everyone has their own opinion - this includes politics, doctors, and other leaders. It’s a hard situation